# Covert an array to a list

Tags: arrays, list

I have the below script I want the list to be something like this [970, 228, 158, 207,.....] not like this :

[237, 242, 248]], dtype=uint8), array([[236, 239, 246],

```
    import numpy as np

from PIL import Image
import PIL


im = Image.open(r"C:\Users\Desktop 1\Desktop\cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg")
img_arr = np.array(im)
a = list(img_arr)
print(a)
print(type(img_arr))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import PIL


im = Image.open(r"***.JPG")
img_arr = np.array(im)
a = img_arr.tolist()
a = np.concatenate((a), axis=None)
print(a)
print(type(img_arr))
```

Comment: that is what i m looking but when type print(type(a)) I want it to be a list not numpy.ndarray